# How to insert one line in Applet?

Tags: java, swing, applet, line, joptionpane

I would like to insert one line between `"total charges"`and `"Thank you..."`

Here is the code I have made so far:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total Charges : RM" + dollar.format(totalCharges) + "Thank you please come again");
```

How can I do this? 
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HTML formatting.  Something like this should work:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
    "<html><body>Total Charges : RM" 
    + dollar.format(totalCharges) 
    + "<br>Thank you please come again");
```